# ConTeXt: Placing caption of wide figure centered in the margin, below figure

Tags: floats, captions, margins, context

**Goal**

I want to be able to put the caption (I will use no text, but only the "Figure X" label) centered in the margin, *below* the image, without disturbing the space between the image and the text that comes after.

**Try 1**

My first try was to put the image anchored to `inner` and then put the caption in the margin. But then the caption is not below the image:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\definefloat[widefigure][figure]

\setupfloat[widefigure]
    [location=inner,
    ]

\setupcaption[widefigure]
    [location={rightmargin,low},
     style=\tfxx,
     align=middle,
     width=\rightmarginwidth,
    ]

\showframe

\starttext
\input ward
\startplacewidefigure
\blackrule[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth),height=1in,color=darkyellow]
\stopplacewidefigure
\input ward
\stoptext
```

[image: caption in the wrong place]

**Try 2**

My second try was to put the image in the rightmargin (allowing it to be wider to stick into the text). Then I can use the `bottom` key for the margin. Now the status between the image and caption looks fine, but there is instead vertical space between the image and the text that comes after that I don't know how to get rid of. Example:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\definefloat[widefigure][figure]

\setupfloat[widefigure]
    [location=rightmargin,
     spaceafter=,
    ]

\setupcaption[widefigure]
    [location={bottom},
     style=\tfxx,
     align=middle,
     width=\rightmarginwidth,
     height=0pt,
     spaceafter=,
    ]

\showframe

\starttext
\input ward
\startplacewidefigure
\blackrule[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth),height=1in,color=darkyellow]
\stopplacewidefigure
\input ward
\stoptext
```

[image: too much space below the figure]

**Where I have looked**

I'm reading the [ConTeXt command's reference](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf), but I cannot find a suitable option for `\setupfloatcaption` (which seem to be the correct place to look) that gives what I'm looking for. Also, from the final section on caption handling in [the details manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf) I'm not able to see how to achieve this.

**Summary**

Is there a way to either 1) lower the caption in the first example so that it is below the image or 2) reduce the space after the image in the second one (the caption should be independent of what is coming next)?

Comment: Based on a quick scan of `strc-flt.mkiv`, I don't think that what you are trying to do is possible with the built in options. One option that I can think of is to use ornaments (see Chapter 7 of [The Details](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual), and create an ornament which includes the figure number. But you may also with to ask on the context mailing list

Comment: Many thanks, @Aditya! I realized that I actually can get rid of the white space after if I add `\blank[overlay]` before the text that comes after. But that does not work well if I postpone images. I should perhaps either try to use the ornaments (I guess that should, in principle, work), or send an email to the email list.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Aditya, one can use ornaments. I leave that as an answer since it might be useful for others, but wait for other answers that might be cleaner.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\definefloat[widefigure][figure]

\setupfloat[widefigure]
    [location=rightmargin,
    ]

\setupcaption[widefigure]
    [location=none,
    ]

\define[2]\WideFigure{%
\startplacewidefigure[reference={#1}]
\layeredtext
[corner={right,bottom},location={left,bottom}]
[offset=0pt]
{\framed[width=\rightmarginwidth,height=5ex,frame=off]{\bfxx\in{Figure}[#1]}}
{#2}
\stopplacewidefigure
}

\showframe

\starttext
\input ward
\WideFigure{fig:test}{%
\blackrule[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth),height=1in,color=darkyellow]}
\input ward
\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: Solution using ornaments]